# Excel: Split ; separated cell values into columns and then shift in consecutive rows

Tags: vba, excel

I'm in the situation described by fig.1 where I have a cell with the reference name and a cell with one or more semicolon separated emails associated to the same reference. I'd like to split the cells contaning more than one email stacking them consecutively and copying the refence name. Is it possible to do this with a VBA Macro in Excel 2007? I know the existence of the "Split in columns" command, but I don't know how to automatically shift the columns in rows and copying the reference name. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Please let us know what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
Sub SplitColumnB()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = [B2]
    Do While r.Value <> ""
        res = Split(r.Value, " ; ")
        i = 0
        For Each resStr In res
            If i > 0 Then r.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert xlDown
            r.Offset(IIf(i > 0, 1, 0)).Value = resStr
            r.Offset(IIf(i > 0, 1, 0), -1).Value = Right(resStr, Len(resStr) - InStr(resStr, "@"))
            i = i + 1
        Next
        Set r = r.Offset(IIf(i > 0, i, 1))
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice and compact solution, but there is a little misunderstanding. I don't want to copy the name after the @ as you did, but the values in the cells which are before the cell containing the email. I'm sure that you can easily correct the solution! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code. Replace all instances of `Sheet1` with the name of your worksheet.

```vb
Sub test()

    Dim Ref As String
    Dim Eid As String
    Dim RefR()
    Dim EidR()

    Rcnt = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row
    K = 0
    L = 0

    For i = 2 To Rcnt
        Ref = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value
        Temp = Split(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value, ";")
        K = K + 1
        ReDim Preserve RefR(1 To K)
        RefR(K) = Ref

        For j = LBound(Temp) To UBound(Temp)
            If L <= UBound(Temp) Then
                ReDim Preserve EidR(Rcnt, L)
                L = UBound(Temp)
            End If
            EidR(K, j) = Temp(j)
        Next j
    Next i

    RowValue = 2
    For i = 1 To UBound(RefR)
        For j = 0 To L

            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & RowValue).Value = RefR(i)
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & RowValue).Value = Trim(EidR(i, j))
            RowValue = RowValue + 1
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```